# Unable to fetch an email in Weibo

Tags: android, weibo, sinaweibo

I have added scope email in Weibo SDK still I'm not getting user email in the result. Then I implemented its API 
 https://api.weibo.com/2/account/profile/email.json

I am getting this exception:

```
{"error":"access_denied","error_code":21330,"request":"/2/account/profile/email.json"}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I mailed Weibo Api Tech Team for this question, they said this api `account/profile/email` is currently offline due to policy adjustment, in other words, this api is unavaliable anymore.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can retrieve email in Weibo

Comment: I think the answer is "no". My solution is to change the registration flow to ask user's email after Weibo oauth.